# Python program that repeatadly counts odd and even digits and sums them up

Tags: python, loops

Given a number, how can we count the number of odd and even digits and then sum them up in Python? Apparently if you do this repeat this process, you will always end up with 123 for any number. I would like to do this in Python.

Example:

- 5683474
- 4 3 = 7 (4 even and 3 odd) 4, 3 and 7 now make up a new number.
- 1 2 = 3

We've ended up with 123 and this process works with every number.

Comment: Is this homework? If it is, people here won't do your homework for you. You'll have to at least give an idea of what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please post what you tried so far... You did try *something* yourself before posting here, have you not?

Comment: Downvoting for "I would prefer exact code."

Comment: Don't edit your question to change it to a completely different question. Try asking another one. [However, if you do open "what does HTML stand for" as a different question, it will probably get closed for various reasons].

Answer (score 4):

Since this is probably homework, here are a few hints:

- You can convert an integer into a string using the `str()` function
- You can convert a string into a list of characters using the `list()` function.
- You can convert a character to an integer (assuming it's a number) using the `int()` function
- An even number has a remainder of 0 when divided by 2

Answer (score 4):

```
s = raw_input('Enter a number')
while s!= '123':
    s = "%s"*3%(sum(~int(i)&1 for i in s),sum(int(i)&1 for i in s),len(s))
    print s
```

Comment: You'd be the first person I've seen in a long time to use bitwise operations in Python. +1 for lulziness.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: You'll just have to get out more often :-)